# Facebook login php sdk error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I tried creating a facebook login using facebook php sdk, and currently I am having this error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must
>   match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain
>   of one of the App's domains.

I have already added the site url of my website, and also placed it in the app domain.

My application is still in sandbox mode, so right now I have no idea why facebook is giving that error. Have I missed something from my settings?

my domain(example):

```
www.mydomain.com
```

My website is on a subdomain :

```
www.mydomain.com/websitesample/website
```

My app domain and site url both have the same value:

> http://www.mydomain.com

Aside from these settings I have double checked my app id and app secret. I have waited for at least 15 minutes because I have read somewhere that when saving changes on your application you'd still have to wait for the changes to propagate through facebook's servers. What else could I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use as `App Domains`: ***mydomain.com***

So every subdomain will work.

Btw - www.mydomain.com/websitesample/website <- websitesample/website isn't a subdomain, it's a directory and this won't cause any problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. Visit developer.facebok.com
2. Select facebook application
3. Enter the
   settings tab on the left side
4. Available on the page, basic tab, click to Add Platform
5. Click to website
6. Your website type to Site URL section ex: yourdomain.com/xx/..
7. Click to Save changes.

best regards.

Answer (score 0):

My colleague and I have gotten to have fixed it somehow. We added the subdomains in the app domains and it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

Check in settings page as:

App Domains:  www.mydomain.com,

Canvas Page:   https://apps.facebook.com/app_name,

Canvas URL:    http://mydomain.com